# Creating sessions in java socket programming with one server and multiple clients

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I am a novice programmer in java.
I have created a program which is similar to a chat application using socket programming.
I haven't used threads.

My question is:

Whenever a client1 wants to communicate to another client2 via the sever how can i know which client is communicating.

I thought if i could differentiate all clients from server side by using sessions it would be easier. Just a random thought.

why this question??

I want to know this because i have stored the adressess of clients in a file along with a sequence number to make the messages visible to the pair alone globally. Whenever a client sends a message it prefixes it with a sequence number which is got from the client1 client2 pair stored in that file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Im just a learner in java. I apologize for any obscurity in my question.

Comment: Isn't each client Socket object unique for each client? Are you communicating with multiple logical clients using single TCP connection? Ideally you could create some Session class and use a map which maps socket to your socket object.

Comment: yeah. as u said. i use one connection for connecting multiple clients.

Comment: I actually want to know the location staus of client2 from within client1. I invoked a method which requests the server to tell if the client2 is within the network of client1. Now the sever has to know which client wants to know the status of client2. Finding client 1 is not visualisable for me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to make a thread to open a socket because it helps in your GUI processing. And the point that you want to see client names can be done by this steps:-

Add an editbox and enter your name (client name) and send this name along with the message and at server-side, split message and name so that you can determine which message is sent by whom.

Ex:- Client name is Alex and the message is "hi" then the data which will be sent is something like "Alex+hi". Now split this message using **split()** function in java at the server-side.
Hope this encoding and decoding will help you.